# google maps OutOfMemory

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have android google maps v2. I need post thumbnails on map. When I do it with 300-500 images ( 3-6 kb every ) it works fine, but when I'm try post 800 and more images I got OutOfMemory error. I long banging my head against the wall, finally I try write images to external storage and post images from there, but i got OutOfMemory again.

P.S. When I just load thumbnails from network and write it to external storage it works fine.

My question is: Can I post 10-000 images (for example) on google maps without OutOfMemory error? Help me please. 
Don't let me please destroy my head.

my code which sets image on my map.

```
marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(position)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(distance)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Methods
                            .BitmapResize(70, 70, (BitmapDrawable) photo)
                            .getBitmap())));
```

Comment: well, what if you enable largeHeap? still the same error?

Comment: Are you loading the thumbnails in a thread?

Comment: Yes, download complete in foreground stream.

Comment: @nikis Large heap can only increase memory, but it will not solve my problem.

Comment: @Vlad Palamarchuk it can solve your problem. But there is another way: optimize your algorithm or download smaller images

Comment: @nikis When I just load images to external storage its work fine, but only when I post images onto map my heap begins to burn slowly and as result OutOfMemory error. Images is 50x50 pixels.